# Making section the correct size in HTML5

Tags: css, html

I am learning HTML5. I am trying to create a section in the browser that is a certain size and things like buttons text etc are placed inside it depending on what button is pressed. The trouble is I cant seem to make the section smaller than the screen or start a set amount below the header so that is has a "boarder" all the way around it showing the background image. Here is the HTML5 I have

```
    <body>
<header>
    <nav id="nav1">
        <button id="b1"> Goals </button>
        <button id="b2"> Habits </button>
        <button id="b3"> Diary </button>
    </nav>
</header>
<section id="goals">

</section>
```

Here is the CSS I have for the section

```
   section
   {
height: 700px;
background-color:blue; 
overflow:auto;
top:50px;
transform:translateY(20px);

   }
```

Comment: Look into `min-height` and `max-height` properties in CSS to start you down the right path.

Comment: Super cheers used them and set the margin and position to relative and worked really well.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/wcpkM/

see this Fiddle, also look at @TylerH comment.

When using

```
top: 50px;
```

like you did, you either need position: absolute, relative or fixed.
Would not recommend doing that unless absolute necessary.

Comment: That's great sorted it, first time I have seen JSFiddle can see that helping going forward

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `top:50px` do `margin-top: 50px`. `Top: 50px` will only work if you have a `position:` rule.

Your sizing problem is because you haven't defined a width.